# DNS resolution fails while torrents are running

Tags: networking, bandwidth, utorrent

When I turn on torrents, I am unable to use the internet for anything else. This primarily affects my web browsing where the browser fails to resolve hosts.

Once torrents are turned off, I am able to browse as per usual again.

I am looking to change the way uTorrent is configured so as to prevent this from happening.

Under uTorrent settings, I tried changing the following values without any success:

- Bandwidth -> Number of Connections -> Global max number of connections: previously `500`, now `100`
- Bandwidth -> Number of Connections -> Maximum number of connected peers per torrent: previously `200`, now `25`

I realize that I may not get the best possible download speed if I change other settings but I am trying to find a balance between running torrents and being able to use the internet for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Limit download to less than your download capacity, and upload to less than your upload capacity. The number of connections is irrelevant.

If you don't know your download/upload capacity, check the bill from your internet provider, or use a service like speedtest.

The menus of uTorrent are self explaining, but here is a step by step guide: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/optimizing-torrent-speed.htm

Comment: Can you post the contents of that link in case it dies?

Comment: I decided not to, because the menu is really self explaining and the link is not necessary. Also it's very likely that the menu will change in a newer version, causing the specific instructions to be incorrect.

Comment: Can you at least link to the help from utorrent which would likely change accordingly to the program?

Comment: _"If you don't know your download/upload capacity, check the bill from your internet provider, or use a service like speedtest."_ actually you need to use a speedtest to find out if you are getting the speed that you pay for.  your isp may need to fix the line between you and their office.